# Path components of mapping space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be CW complexes and denote by $\operatorname{map}(A,B)$ their mapping space. Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are connected, that both spaces have finitely many nontrivial homotopy groups and that all homotopy groups of $A$ and $B$ are finite. I am trying to show that $\operatorname{map}(A,B)$ then has only finitely many path components, i.e. that the set of homotopy classes of maps between $A$ and $B$ is finite.

This is implicitly claimed in a paper that I read, but I am unable to find an argument for this. I would be grateful for any help in that regard.

Comment: If $B$ is suitable (i.e. nilpotent) you can take a Postnikov decomposition of it and induct on the resulting fibre sequences of mapping spaces.